# I have checked manually in my db but my list is returning empty?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have tried to get only travels from my db where source_name, destination is particular. i want get travels list from my db using prepared statement. But I am unable to get the same.

```
package com.indiabus1.Dao;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.indiabus1.beans.*;
import com.indiabus1.Dao.*;
import com.indiabus1.*;
import com.indiabus1.Dao.ConnectionFactory;
import com.indiabus1.beans.BusSelectionBeans;

public class BusSelectionDAO {


Connection connection;

public BusSelectionDAO(){}

private static Connection getConnection() 
        throws SQLException, 
            ClassNotFoundException 
{
    Connection con = ConnectionFactory.
            getInstance().getConnection();
    return con;
}




public static List<BusSelectionBeans> getRecords( String s, String s2){  

    List<BusSelectionBeans> list=new ArrayList<BusSelectionBeans>();  

    try{  

         Connection con=getConnection();  

         System.out.println(s+" to "+s2);

         String SQL="select travels from new_trips.dt_trips where                       
        source_name='"+s+"' and destination_name='"+s2+"' limit 5"; 
         PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement(SQL);  

        //ps.setString(1, s);
       // ps.setString(2, s2);

        ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();  

        while(rs.next()){  

        BusSelectionBeans d=new BusSelectionBeans(); 

        String x1=rs.getString(1);


        // String x2=rs.getString(1);
        // String x3=rs.getString(2);


        d.setBusOperator(x1);   

        // d.setS_name(x2);  
        //  d.setD_name(x3);



        list.add(d);  

        }  

        con.close();  

    }catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}  


      System.out.println(list);

     return list;  
   }  


   }
```

Why I am getting my list is returning empty, but manually the SQL query result is given.

Comment: right now in your code you don't set any string to the statement. print out the query which is currently executed and check if that gives you results. also [prepared statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) work with ? as placeholder

Comment: i have checked that also but still its its giving empty list...

Comment: First of all, I don't know why you are using preparedStatement when you don't actually have a preparedStatement as a query, you should be using executeQuery.

Comment: give us the values you want to search for, as well as the query which is executed and the query which you execute manually

Comment: What means `new_trips.dt_trips`?

Comment: select travels from new_trips.dt_trips where source_name='Abu Road' and destination_name='Ahmedabad' limit 5");

Comment: new_trips.dt_trips   its table name

Comment: i got it...i didnt trim..s s2.

Comment: @PrasadOUCE could have told you if you just for once would have given the full query which was executed, but no, better waste hours saying you did everything right

Comment: sorry man, i'm beginer

Comment: Thanks for all ..spontaneous responses

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but probably `System.out.println(list);` won't give you anything senseful, if you validate the result by this.

You may loop over the list and print them.
`for(BusSelectionBeans d_ins : list){/*print stuff of d_ins*/}`

Also for sake of SQL Injection, go for(back to) prepared statements as you commented out.

**Weird possibilities**
If you not getting any print operation to `stdout`(`System.out`), then it could be forwarded to another out stream, or in some situations it needs flush. make sure about it too.
Example, write the result in a file, rather `stdout`(since it could not be `stdout` really)

Comment: select travels from dt_trips where source_name=? and destination_name=? limit 5");  
          ps.setString(1, s);
            ps.setString(2, s2);
            
            ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();  
            
            while(rs.next()){  
             
            BusSelectionBeans d=new BusSelectionBeans(); 
             
            String x1=rs.getString(1);
             
            System.out.println(x1);
             
            // String x2=rs.getString(1);
            // String x3=rs.getString(2);
  
            d.setBusOperator(x1);

Comment: stll its not comming

Comment: If you not getting any `exception/error` then, so the query returns nothing. Also make sure you are working with correct database context.

Comment: i am double sure because ....with the same connection there were two servlets alredy excecuted before this...this is my final loop/servlet

Comment: @PrasadOUCE Alright, so in servlet context, how do you expected to check the write(print) operations over the `stdout`(`System.out`). As it's in a servlet, you may write down the result to a request to make sure everything is great. Or find the redirected `stdout`, and check the file. e.g. it's `catalina.out` for tomcat. So again, as it's in servlet/web, forget `System.out`, and print the data to target user for valdiation

Comment: i am not doing inside servlet...is DAO class associated to that servlet

Comment: @PrasadOUCE The servlet context is the same for all of the module. One does not simply have two `stdout` inside one application scope at one time. I don't know where you are trying to fetch any `stdout` print/write results, but as far as I know, they could be redirected to a file. The best way is printing them with a test servlet to user http request

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced this also in the past.
Here are the things that might help:

1. The first thing that you might want to do is to double check your database connection. Are you sure that you are connecting to the correct database? There are cases where you are using 2 databases and you just forgot to change the database you were using. e.g. official_db, official_db_test or db1 and db2.
2. Check your parameters s and s2? There might be problems with their values since they are string and might have problems during parsing.
3. To determine if there are values inside rs, try putting System.out.println("rs has row/s.") inside while(rs.next()){  .... };

Comment: i have checked  and have confirmed ,...my connection is perfect, s, s2 are fine they are ok....but still only giving empty...

Comment: i got it...i didnt trim..s s2.